# Moving shadows in Three.JS

Tags: three.js, shadows

Is there a way to dynamically change the 'position' of the light which casts the shadow. I only want an area around the player casted with shadows, and not the whole map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done by moving the shadowCameraTop/Right/Bottom/Left and then updating the projection matrix, or setting the position of the light itself